# Вывод элементов массива в заданном диапазоне

Tags: java

Мне нужно вывести новый массив, перебрав старый и выбрать от туда числа которые находятся в между числами int start и int end. Но у меня выдает не то что нужно.

```
    int[] numbers = {5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15, 20};
    int start = 8;
    int end = 12;
    int[] nums = new int[end - start - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if (numbers[i] >= start && numbers[i] <= end) {
                nums[j] = numbers[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Получается массив [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

```
   for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
       if (i == 0) {
           System.out.print("[");
       }
        System.out.print(nums[i]);
       if (i < nums.length - 1) {
           System.out.print(", ");
       } else {
           System.out.print("]");
       }
    }
```

Comment: А где код вывода этих чисел?

Comment: Кстати, зачем тут два цикла?

Comment: Кстати, дли массива nums длина указана неправильная, т.к. количество элементов заранее неизвестно

Comment: Код вывода приложил

Comment: Для того, что бы массив новый, записывался по порядку индексов отсортированные числа

Comment: У меня заранее все известно ибо массив указан выше, который сортируется

Comment: А вот теперь представь, что у тебя всё так же start=8, end=12, а в массиве, вместо 12 у тебя 15, а вместо 8 - 2. Сразу будет облом

Comment: *"Для того, что бы массив новый, записывался по порядку индексов отсортированные числа"* --- достаточно просто делать push в массив без всяких циклов (там максимум счётчик можно где-то вести для него и увеличивать на 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле, проблем тут очень много. Но если отвечать на конкретный вопрос: на каждой итерации по основному массиву, запускается ещё один цикл и заносит во все ячейки `nums` числа этой итерации (при соблюдении условия, конечно же).  Так если `numbers[i]` будет равен 8, то запуститься внутренний цикл и во все ячейки `nums` положит 8. Потом на другом цикле - все ячейки затрёт девятками и т.д.

Если последней цифрой (или числом),  подходящим под условие, поставить, например 11, то будет три раза 11.

Если откинуть все недочёты и некорректности кода, то **конкретно эту проблему** можно решить убрав цикл и просто добавив свой счётчик и прибавляя его "вручную". Получится что-то типа такого:

```
int[] nums = new int[end - start - 1];
int numsIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {        
    if (numbers[i] >= start && numbers[i] <= end) {
        nums[numsIndex] = numbers[i];
        numsIndex++;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Но вот это `int[] nums = new int[end - start - 1];` осталось нехорошее, притом что start и end - не индексы

Comment: @MBo да, я знаю. Я это даже ТС'у в комментариях писал и несколько раз специально упомянул что **решаем только конкретно эту проблему**. По факту там ещё есть нюансы